# S3FileInfo in Amazon S3 .NET SDK returning false always

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, sdk, file-exists, fileinfo

I have a simple test verifying that I can check if a file exists in S3.  However, when I run the test, using the `S3FileInfo` class (as recommended to check existence), it will always return `false`.  I added other methods of verification to see if maybe the file was not being uploaded correctly, but it is.

**The Test** :

```
[Fact]
public void FileExists()
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\\dummy\\path\\to\\file.txt";

    using (var client = clientFactory.GetClient())
    {
        var objectRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
        objectRequest.BucketName = config.BucketName;
        objectRequest.ContentBody = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        objectRequest.Key = fileName;

        var response = client.PutObject(objectRequest);
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.HttpStatusCode);

        var request = new ListObjectsV2Request();
        request.BucketName = config.BucketName;

        var listResponse = client.ListObjectsV2(request);
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, listResponse.HttpStatusCode);
        var contains = listResponse.S3Objects.Any(o => o.Key == fileName && o.BucketName == config.BucketName);
        Assert.True(contains);

        var putObject = listResponse.S3Objects.First(o => o.Key == fileName && o.BucketName == config.BucketName);
        Assert.Equal(config.BucketName, putObject.BucketName);
        Assert.Equal(fileName, putObject.Key);
        Assert.InRange(putObject.LastModified, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
        Assert.Equal(36, putObject.Size);

        var getResponse = client.GetObject(config.BucketName, fileName);
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, getResponse.HttpStatusCode);
        Assert.Equal(config.BucketName, getResponse.BucketName);
        Assert.Equal(fileName, getResponse.Key);
        Assert.InRange(getResponse.LastModified.ToLocalTime(), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));

        using (var responseStream = getResponse.ResponseStream)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Assert.Equal(objectRequest.ContentBody, content);
        }

        var info = new S3FileInfo(client, config.BucketName, fileName);
        Assert.True(info.Exists);
    }
}
```

All assertions in this test pass - except for the last one.  I know it's not a delay issue in S3, because the earlier assertions pass.  So, I figure one of two things is happening: either there is something wrong with what I am doing with the `S3FileInfo` class, or there is a bug with the SDK I have found.  I consider the latter very unlikely, but the command is so simple that I don't know how I might be doing the former.  I am using version 3.3.12 of the .Net Amazon S3 SDK.

**Update** : Updating to 3.3.12.1 did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon converts backslash to forward slash when you upload to S3 from Windows.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=138263

So when you list your object back with `ListObjectsV2`, the filename won't exist.